# how can I adapt the following code to make i of the array increment on button click?

Tags: javascript

with the following code how can I increment the array based on onclick. I currently have this on a timer but want it to use the onclick option to change the picture/increment the array

```
   var i=0;
var images = [];
var time = 1000;

images[0] = 'img1.jpg';
images[1] = 'img2.jpg';
images[2] = 'img3.png';

//change image function
function changeIMG()
{
    document.slide.src = images[i];

    if(i < images.length - 1)
    {
        i += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        i = 0;
    }
    setTimeout("changeIMG()", time);
}
window.onload = changeIMG;
```

Comment: Have you simply tried setting up a button with a `click` event handler that has `i++` in it?

Answer (score 0):

First, let's add the button:

```
<button id='btn'>Change Image</button>
```

Now, adding some JavaScript to handle the button's `onclick` event:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.onclick = changeIMG;
```